# how to upload blob using REST in development storage?

Tags: c#, azure

How to upload Microsoft Azure Blobs using REST in development Storage?
please help me to upload and download azure blobs using REST .

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you check out David Pallman's complete Azure Storage REST samples. He demonstrates every Azure Storage operation in RAW rest examples using .NET

http://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/